# Mystery heap corruption, why?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, heap-memory

I've had a bug in my code for some time that I can't figure out. Maybe I'm just blind, but this bug doesn't make much sense, because from what I can see, this code is flawless. I speculate that there may be corruption from somewhere else, but I figured I'd paste my problem code here just in case.

I know there is heap corruption because I get the standard **Error** message followed by a free() invalid next size message.
I've included what I feel to be relevant. Heap corruption occurs on the second free(FileBuf);

```
while ((DirPtr = readdir(ProcDir)))
{
    if (AllNumeric(DirPtr->d_name) && atoi(DirPtr->d_name) >= InObj->ObjectPID &&
        atoi(DirPtr->d_name) <= InObj->ObjectPID + 10) /*Search 10 PIDs forward.*/
    {
        char TChar;

        snprintf(FileName, sizeof FileName, "/proc/%s/cmdline", DirPtr->d_name);

        if (!(Descriptor = fopen(FileName, "r")))
        {
            closedir(ProcDir);
            return 0;
        }

        FileBuf = malloc(MAX_LINE_SIZE);
        /*Scroll further down to find the free()s.*/
        for (Inc = 0; (TChar = getc(Descriptor)) != EOF && Inc < MAX_LINE_SIZE - 1; ++Inc)
        {
            FileBuf[Inc] = TChar;
        }
        FileBuf[Inc] = '\0';

        fclose(Descriptor);

        for (Inc = 0, Inc2 = NumSpaces; Inc2 != 0; ++Inc)
        { /*We need to replace the NUL characters with spaces.*/
            if (FileBuf[Inc] == '\0')
            {
                --Inc2;
                FileBuf[Inc] = ' ';
            }
        }

        if (!strcmp(FileBuf, InObj->ObjectStartCommand))
        {
            unsigned long RealPID;

            free(FileBuf);
            FileBuf = NULL;
            snprintf(FileName, sizeof FileName, "%s", DirPtr->d_name);
            closedir(ProcDir);

            RealPID = atoi(FileName);

            if (UpdatePID)
            {
                InObj->ObjectPID = RealPID;
            }

            return RealPID;

        }
        /*And here is the problem.*/
        free(FileBuf);
    }
}
closedir(ProcDir);

return 0;
```

Comment: How do you know there's heap corruption?  What's happening that you're not expecting? "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and include valid code to reproduce it." "Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the **expected results**."

Comment: Why do you allocate and free FileBuf on each iteration of the while loop?  Why not just allocate once in advance and free one after the loop?

Comment: Something depressing occurred to me, thank you, I'll see.

Comment: This seems like one of those places in C where a `goto` might be a rather clean solution;  you could put all your cleanup and return code in one place.  Instead of multiple paths with `return` and `free`, you could simply set the return value, then `goto finish;` and free the memory, close the ProcDir, and return return the return value.

Comment: Have you tried using `valgrind` to track down the problem? That should be your first inclination, not posting to SO.

Comment: Ok This is what i think is happening, you are freeing twice an address, whch gives a HUGE error normally. To avoid this errors you must frr(ptr); ptr=NULL; because if you free a NULL pointer it does nothing. 
So to clarify, FileBuf is freed, lets say 0x01 is Filebuff address, then if FileBuf is not set to null, your second free tries to free it again, giving you a heap corruption.

So Good practice
free(ptr);
ptr = NULL;

Comment: @Sinn I had that thought too, but there are only two `free`s, and the first one is followed by a return statement, so if the first one happens, the second one doesn't.

Comment: Could you please include the actual error output that you're getting?

Comment: As long as your at it, where is the decl for FileName. Please, *please*, post complete code.

Comment: Thanks guys, It turns out that it was a problem in another place that caused this. I cleaned up all the horror story code while I was at it. I also posted an answer that elaborates better.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Indeed, I removed the heap stuff altogether in the end, though I made sure I fixed their problem before I did. It was unnecessary. I imagine I did it because I expected to dynamically set aside space, but then I must have decided that MAX_LINE_SIZE was good enough, and forgot to switch to using the stack.

Answer (score -1):

FOUND! AdvancedPIDFind() works by counting the number of spaces in the start command to reassemble /proc/PID/cmdline from it's NUL-separatedness, but if one is adding multiple commands separated by ampersands or adds an extra space, this is not included in /proc/cmdline. This causes the memory corruption error when we fly off the end of allocated memory. I am writing the fix now. Thanks for putting up with me. Seems like I always find the answer right after I hit 'post'.